# unsupported operand types for * : 'float' and 'decimal'

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal

```
for a in range(0,size):
    et = 0.0023*ralist[rows[a][2]] * ( 0.5*(rows[a][3] + rows[a][4])  + 17.8 ) * ( rows[a][3] - rows[a][4])**(0.5)
    eto_values.insert(a,et)
```

When I try to run the code, I get the following error:

```
unsupported operand types for * : 'float' and  'decimal'
```

I have tried using `decimal.Decimal()` function also. Can someone please tell me how to clear this error?

Comment: what is ralist? I am sure you are messing up with that.

Comment: It is just an array. It has all 'decimal' type values in it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cant multiply or devise `float` and `decimal.Decimal()` types, what I would suggest is multiplying by `Decimal('0.0023')` and `Decimal('0.5')`:

```py
for a in range(0,size)
  et = Decimal('0.0023')*ralist[rows[a][2]] * ( Decimal('0.5')*(rows[a][3] + rows[a][4]) + 17.8 ) * ( rows[a][3] - rows[a][4])**(0.5)
  eto_values.insert(a,et)
```

Comment: "`Decimal(0.0023)` and `Decimal(0.5)`" - no! If you're going to hardcode a Decimal into your source, always construct it from a string, like `Decimal('0.0023')`, to avoid having the value rounded to what can be represented in a float.

Comment: `devise` → `divide`?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> Decimal(1.2) * Decimal(3.4)
Decimal('4.079999999999999742428258287')
>>> Decimal(1.2) * 3.4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'float'
```